# Ballerinalang configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, ballerina

I was trying to run a ballerina program on IntelliJ Idea. Then, Edit configuration appears and it says

```
Error: Main run kind is selected, but the file does not contain a main function.
```

What should I do ? And what should I select in Program Arguments.

source code:

```
import ballerina.net.http;
import ballerina.lang.messages;

@http:BasePath {value:"/helloservice"}
service helloService {

    @http:GET {}
    @http:PATH {value:"/hello?name={name}"}
    resource hello (message m, @http:QueryParam {value:"name"} string name) {
        string respStr = "Hello, World " + name + "!\n";

        message responce = {};
        messages:setStringPayload(response, respStr);

        reply response;
    }
    }
```

Comment: can you post your code to the question?

Comment: This error occurs when there is no entrypoint (service or main function) in the source code.

Comment: @AnuruddhaLankaLiyanarachchi

Comment: You seem to be running a very old version of ballerina. Syntax is very different now. I suggest you to download the latest ballerina-platform distribution(https://ballerina.io/downloads/) and try out the "Hello World" main function sample(https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/hello-world.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the issue here is, you have manually created a **main run configuration** and trying to run a **service** using that. Please select the **service** run kind in configuration as shown below.

[image]

Also, you don't have to manually create a run configurations. IntelliJ IDEA plugin can automatically detect the run kind when you run a main function or services using gutter run icon like below.

[image: Running a file with no configurations]

Run configuration is automatically created.

[image: Configuration is created]

If you first run a main and then run a service, the run configuration will be automatically changed according to that as well. So no manual intervention is needed.

On the side notes, the code seems to have much older Ballerina syntax and I would advice using the latest Ballerina syntax to avoid any issues with the latest IntelliJ IDEA plugin. Please refer [Ballerina examples](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/) for latest syntax.